# HTML Checkbox - allow to check mutliple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have html code, which displays content in grid format, that is a row with three columns each, and each input field would be able to check. However, i am not able to check multiple checkboxes with below code. Whatever checkbox i choose, only the first box in the list is triggered and checked. Others remain ng-prestine. What would be the issue with my code

```
 <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="(key, allergyList) in  filteredAllergies track by $index">
         <td ng-repeat="allergy in allergyList track by $index">
             <div class="ice-form-checkbox">
                 <input id="condition" ng-model="selectedAllergy" type="checkbox"/><label for="condition"><span>{{allergy.allergyName}}</span></label>
             </div>
         </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Do they all have the same id?

Comment: You are using `ng-repeat` and then have a fixed `ID` on your `input` so, every `input` allergy in allergyList will have `id="condition"` which is incorrect syntactically

Comment: What do you mean by "only the first box is triggered and checked". Visually, the right check boxes are checked, but maybe you expect a particular value to end up in selectedAllergy?

Answer (score 1):

You are giving only one single variable as a model to the checkboxes. You should atribute an array, like this: (Run the Code Snippet to see it working)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.options =         
    [
     [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}],
        [{id: 4}, {id: 5}, {id: 6}],
        [{id: 9}, {id: 8}, {id: 9}]
    ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in options">
      <td ng-repeat="item in row">
        <p>Op {{item.id}}</p>
        <input ng-model="item.value" type="checkbox" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div ng-repeat="row in options">{{row}}
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The model, selectedAllergy, exists in the main scope. Set it to "allergy.selected".

Answer (score -1):

You are using `ng-repeat` and then have a fixed `ID` on your `input` so, every `input` `allergy in allergyList` will have `id="condition"` which is incorrect HTML

This may be causing the effect of only being able to select one checkbox. Try changing it to a class and see what happens.

Comment: The duplicate id does not cause the effect.